# Unable to install .NET framework-3.5 on Windows 10 using DISM (error - 0x800f081f)

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, .net-framework

It's been almost 3 days and I have tried almost all the methods provided on internet to install .NET framework on Windows 10 but no luck.

**Method 1.** When I tried to install it from control panel by enabling the feature it gets stuck for at "Downloading required files screen and never completes.

**Method 2.** After that I found on internet that it can be installed using DISM from iso image, for that I mounted the iso image of windows 10 which I used to install windows on my system and run the following command from windows power shell -
E:\sources\sxs - It is the location of folder inside mounted windows image where microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab file is present.

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:E:\sources\sxs
```

but it is giving the below error -

```
Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

**Method 3.** Tried another command providing the package name this time

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:E:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab
```

But is also failed with below error

```
Processing 1 of 1 - An error occurred - Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package Error: 0x800f0818

Error: 0x800f0818

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

**Method 4.** Then I tried one another solution
which suggests to uninstall already installed .NET Framework version 4.0 and then try method 2 above but is also did not work and I am getting the same erorr.

I am really stumped on this issue and not sure what I am doing wrong or what should I do next, It would be really helpful If I get a solution for this problem here.

PS: When I try this command - DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:NetFX3~~~~
every time after restarting the system it completes till a certain percentage and the stuck, seems like some other process stops it after a while, not sure if this gives any clue

Comment: Did you try control panel>Programs and Features>Turn Windows Features on or off?

Comment: Yes that is the very first method but it does not show any progress after almost 70% completion on progress bar.

Comment: How long did you wait before aborting?

Comment: Almost 45 mins, but because I was not seeing any progress I cancelled it.

Comment: I would try again, this time let it run while you sleep.

Comment: @Moab It did not work , if failed finally after running overnight

Comment: I usually don't like questions like this ("Can't do ___") but you did a great job of laying out your problem and what you've tried so far. good job!